# Why doesn't Bitcoin use a DHT to store its blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, client, full-node

Why doesn't Bitcoin store its blockchain in a DHT, but instead makes each (full) node store the entire blockchain?

<sup>related questions: "[Why doesn't Bitcoin use a DHT for choosing peers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37366/4334)" and "[Why doesn't each node store only a portion of the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/49138/4334)"</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Full nodes don't even need to store the entire blockchain (bitcoin core has a pruning mode). They must process each block at least once to ensure they have the correct UTXO set, then the raw block data can be discarded.